# Debugging Adobe AIR app over USB on ASUS MeMo FHD 10

Tags: android, flash, air, remote-debugging

[image]

adb sees the device, Flash / Flash Builder (CC) doesn't - what am I missing? (the Eclipse IDE that comes with the Android SDK can also debug over USB just fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the ADB to [Flash Builder]\sdks\[sdk Ver.]\lib\android\bin\adb.exe 
from [Android SDK]\platform-tools\adb.exe

See this [link](http://www.solid-thinking.com/getting-flash-builder-and-flash-professional-to-connect-with-the-asus-eee-pad-transformer-on-a-mac/).