# Flash Builder 4.6 Can't debug Android tablet

Tags: android, apache-flex, debugging

I've got a number of devices I use to debug apps with.  I got a new Android tablet (Digital2 Deluxe D2-713G) and Windows (Vista) recognized the drivers and all looks good when I look at device manager.  When I try to debug on the device, I get the "Choose Device" dialog that says it can't find the device.  I've added the following to the android_winusb.inf file in both the x86 and amd64 sections.

;Digital2 Deluxe

%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\Vid_1f3a&Pid_1007&Rev_0230&MI_00
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\Vid_1f3a&Pid_1007&MI_00

What else can I do to make FB see the device?

Comment: btw the tablet has the latest version of AIR and is running the .apk when I downloaded and installed it.

Answer (score 1):

If [Android SDK]\platform-tools\adb.exe can see your Android device, copy the adb.exe from Android-SDK to FLEX-SDK.

[Debugging Adobe AIR app over USB on ASUS MeMo FHD 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135275/debugging-adobe-air-app-over-usb-on-asus-memo-fhd-10/20137962)

Comment: Can your adb(in Android SDK folder) see your device?
"cd [Your Android SDK Path]\platform-tools\adb.exe"
"adb devices"

Comment: Sorry... been out of town all week.  No, adb can't see the device.  However I see it in device manager which seems really odd.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the Flex/AIR sdks are you using?  If you get the latest Apache Flex 4.11 with Adobe AIR 3.9, you will also get the latest Android drivers.  This should ensure that Flash Builder can see your device.
You can download the SDK(s) using the Installer here: [flex.apache.org/installer.html](http://flex.apache.org/installer.html)

Comment: I'm using 4.6.  I downloaded the latest (4.11) and tried using adb devices but it didn't show anything.

Comment: I do see "Android ADB Interface" under "Android Phone" in device manager.